# Register a WindowDelegate of a Window opened with SwiftUIs @Environment(\.openWindow)

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I register  the WindowDelegate of a window to be opened with SwiftUIs @Environment(.openWindow) in a MacOS SwiftUI App.

I tried like this, but none of the window delegate functions fire, the app delegate functions work fine.

```
@main
struct Window_TestApp: App {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
...    
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
...
```

Here is the full sample code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct Window_TestApp: App {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
  
  var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([
      Item.self,
    ])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
    
    do {
      return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
    } catch {
      fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
  }()
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ItemListView()
    }.modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    
    WindowGroup("Item", for: Item.ID.self) { $itemId in
      if let id = itemId {
        ItemWindow(persistentID: id)
      }
      
    }.modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
  }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

    //func application(_ application: NSApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Did Finish louching")
  }
  
  func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    print("applicationShouldTerminate")
    //return .terminateCancel
    return .terminateNow
  }
  
  func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("windowWillClose")
  }
  func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    print("windowShouldClose")
    return true
  }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
  @Query private var items: [Item]
  
  @State private var selectedItem: Item?  = nil
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
      VStack{
        Text("Window Demo").font(.title)
        List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItem) { item in
          HStack{
            Text("\(item.text) created:\(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .shortened))")
            Spacer()
              Button("Open Window"){
                print("Open Window pressed")
                openWindow(value: item.id)
              }
              .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
              .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
          } //HStack
        } // List
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem {
            Button(action: addItem) {
              Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
          }
        }
      } // outer VStack
    } // body
  
  private func addItem() {
    withAnimation {
      let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
      modelContext.insert(newItem)
    }
  }

}

struct ItemView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  @State private var text = ""
  var item: Item
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Item").font(.title)
      Text("Created: \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard)) ")
      Text("Text: \(item.text)")
      TextField("Text", text: $text)
      Button("Close"){
        item.text = text
        dismiss()
      }
    }.padding()
  }
  
  init(item: Item) {
    self.item = item
  }
}

@Model final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var text: String = ""
    
  init(timestamp: Date = Date.now) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        text = "Bla"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want AppKit window delegate callbacks, it would be easier to just use AppKit to open the windows. Otherwise, you'll likely have to resort to NSViewRepresentable to get the `window` from a `View` and then register the delegates.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks, How can I get the NSWindow of the View?